# The hom set of homomorphisms from a finitely generated abelian group to $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to figure out what is $\operatorname{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(M,\mathbb{Z})$ and  $\operatorname{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(M,\mathbb{Q})$ for a finitely generated abelian groups $M$. For the latter, suppose the free part of $M$ is of rank $r$, then $\operatorname{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(M,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}^r$. But I'm not sure how to characterise $\operatorname{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(M,\mathbb{Q})$. For a homomorphism, $M\to \mathbb{Q}$, the image of $M$ is a cyclic group. So a homomorphism $M\to Q$ is defined by the generator in $\mathbb{Q}$ which means $\operatorname{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(M,\mathbb{Q})=\mathbb{Q}$. Is my argument correct?

Comment: Your argument is not correct. It's true that the image of $M$ is cyclic but there are many homomorphisms with the same image. We actually have $\text{Hom}(M, \mathbb{Q}) = \mathbb{Q}^r$.

Comment: Note that if this argument worked it would apply equally well to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any abelian group $G$ -- regarded as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module with the canonical structure -- I will write $\mathrm{T}(G)$ for the *torsion subgroup* of $G$. In general $G/\mathrm{T}(G)$ is torsionless (i.e. has trivial torsion subgroup) and in particular when $G$ is finitely generated its quotient $G/\mathrm{T}(G)$ is likewise finitely generated.

According to a fundamental result in the theory of abelian groups, **any finitely generated torsionless abelian group is necessarily free of finite dimension**, so in the particular case of $G$ finitely generated the quotient $G/\mathrm{T}(G)$ is free and isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. As all free modules are projective, the exact sequence:
$$\{0\} \to \mathrm{T}(G) \to G \to G/\mathrm{T}(G) \to \{0\}$$
splits, which means that $G \approx \mathrm{T}(G) \times \mathbb{Z}^n (\mathbf{Gr})$. So far we have carried out a brief review of the initial part of the structure theory of finitely generated abelian groups.

Now onto the study of the homomorphism group. Since in general we have the following abelian group isomorphism (implemented by a functorial isomorphism, actually):
$$\mathrm{Hom}_{\operatorname{A-\mathbf{Mod}}}\left(\bigoplus_{i \in I}M_i, \prod_{j \in J}N_j\right) \approx \prod_{\substack{i \in I\\j \in J}}\mathrm{Hom}_{\operatorname{A-\mathbf{Mod}}}(M_i, N_j) \quad (\mathbf{Gr})$$
for any families of left $A$-modules $M$ (indexed by $I$) and $N$ (indexed by $J$), we have in particular that:
$$\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Gr}}(G, \mathbb{Q}) \approx \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Gr}}(\mathrm{T}(G), \mathbb{Q}) \times \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Gr}}\left(\mathbb{Z}^n, \mathbb{Q}\right) \quad (\mathbf{Gr}). \tag{*}$$

By virtue of the universal property of free abelian groups, we have the abelian group isomorphism:
$$\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Gr}}\left(\mathbb{Z}^n, \mathbb{Q}\right) \approx \mathbb{Q}^n \quad (\mathbf{Gr}),$$
which fully describes one of the factors in the direct product $({}^*)$ above.

As for the remaining factor, we argue that $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Gr}}(\mathrm{T}(G), \mathbb{Q})$ is *null* as a group, by remarking that in general:

- the direct image through a group morphism of a torsion (abelian) group remains a torsion (abelian) group
- any abelian group which is at the same time torsion and has the property that any nonzero element is free (for $t \in G$ to be free means that $\mathrm{Ann}_{\mathbb{Z}}(t)=\{0\}$ or equivalently $t$ is *not* of finite order) must itself be null
- $\mathbb{Q}$ does have the property that all its nonzero elements are free, property which is easily seen to be hereditary (inherited by any subgroup, that is).

With these observations in place one can easily argue that the image of any group morphism $f \colon F \to \mathbb{Q}$ is null -- when $F$ is a torsion group -- and therefore the hom-set in question only contains the null morphism.

To finalise, you have the description:
$$\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Gr}}(G, \mathbb{Q}) \approx \mathbb{Q}^{\mathrm{dim}_{\mathbb{Z}}\left(G/\mathrm{T}(G)\right)} \quad (\mathbf{Gr})$$
for any *finitely generated* abelian group $G$ ($\mathrm{dim}_{\mathbb{Z}}$ is my notation for the dimension of free abelian groups).

As a concluding remark, since $\mathbb{Q}$ has a natural $(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Q})$-bimodule structure, the hom-set $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Gr}}(G, \mathbb{Q})=\mathrm{Hom}_{\operatorname{\mathbb{Z}-\mathbf{Mod}}}(G, \mathbb{Q})$ can be equipped with a natural $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space structure. Thus, we will always have an isomorphism:
$$\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Gr}}(G, \mathbb{Q}) \approx \mathbb{Q}^{(T)} \quad (\operatorname{\mathbb{Q}-\mathbf{Mod}})$$
for a certain set $T$. With an additional construction (passing to the rational vector space of quotients of $G$ by localisation), the cardinality of this $T$ can be characterized as $|T|=\mathrm{dim}_{\mathbb{Q}}(\mathbb{Q} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} G)^*=\mathrm{dim}_{\mathbb{Q}}\left(\left(\mathbb{Q}^{\times}\right)^{-1}G\right)^*$ (the dimension of the dual of the rational vector space obatined by localising).